# Inject to GWT authorize.net Verified Merchant Seal

Tags: java, gwt, authorize.net

I have gwt app with payment feature. I would like to insert into UIBinder following code (provided by authorize.net for verified merchants. I added my site to Verified Merchant Seal Domains List on authorize.net server):

```
<div class="AuthorizeNetSeal">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="MY_ID";</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js"></script>
        <a href="http://www.authorize.net/" id="AuthorizeNetText" target="_blank">MerchantServices</a>
    </div>
```

I tried following:
UIBinder:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="AuthorizeNetSeal">
        <a href="https://www.authorize.net/" id="AuthorizeNetText" target="_blank">Merchant Services</a>
    </div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and in constructor of the control after initWidget(...)

```
ScriptInjector.fromString("var ANS_customer_id = 'MY_ID';").inject();
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js").inject();
```

Tried scheduleDeferred. Tried setCallback() for ScriptInjector.fromUrl. Success method is called.
But seal doesn't appear. 
please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I created separate HTML page with html code above and inserted it to iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Add `script` elements to the `head` section of your host page. If scripts are small and/or you do not use code splitting, there is little to no advantage in using a ScriptInjector.

Verify with your browser console that the script loads correctly from a URL you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject them in the correct *window*:

```
ScriptInjector.fromString("var ANS_customer_id = 'MY_ID';").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

But the `seal.js` uses `document.write` so it cannot be injected that way anyway, it must be present in the HTML document when loaded by the browser.

You could put this snippet in your HTML host page in a hidden `<div>` that you later *relocate* (`Document.get().getElementById(…)` and other `appendChild` DOM methods) where you want it within your app.
…and you should ask Authorize.net to provide an async version of their script so that if their servers are slow they don't slow down the loading of your app.